# MySQL matching 2 out of 5 fields

Tags: mysql

In MySQL I'm trying to select any row that matches at least 2 fields of the provided data

Eg. I have been given firstName, lastName, dob, website, email and I want any rows that match firstName and lastName, or firstName and email, or website and email etc.

I know I could write a very long winded statement along the lines of 
(this=this AND this=this) OR (this=this etc 
but this query could potentially get really large, especially if we decide we want to match on more than 5 fields.

We will also need to rank the matching rows, so if some rows match 3 instead of only the minimum 2 fields then they should show up higher in the returned results.

I could process this afterwards with PHP, or do multiple SQL queries, I'm just wondering if anyone knows an easier/cleaner way to match this data?

I appreciate any help!
Jo

Comment: I don't think LONG SQL will harm anything

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could count up the matching expressions. MySQL returns 1 for true and 0 for false.

```
WHERE (FirstName = ?) + (LastName = ?) + (... = ?) > 2
```

You can also order using this as well. You will want to sort descending to ensure that the higher matches appear first.

```
ORDER BY ((FirstName = ?) + (LastName = ?) + (... = ?)) DESC
```

Answer (score 4):

As a'r's answer recommended, you can add together values. If you want to use this for ranking, you might not include it in the where clause as he did.

```
SELECT *, ((firstName = @inputFirst) + (lastName = @inputLast) + (dob = @inputDob) + (website = @inputWebsite) + (email = @inputEmail)) as Matches
FROM mytable
HAVING Matches > 1
ORDER BY Matches DESC
```

I don't have access to a mysql db to test this syntax at the moment, but I believe it should work properly.

Comment: This is what I was thinking, except I think you'd want `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`.

Comment: @wiseguy why HAVING? There's no grouping here, and no need to filter *after* the ordering

Comment: Because `Matches` isn't an actual column in a table. `WHERE` puts conditions on table columns, while `HAVING` puts conditions on resultset columns.

Comment: MySQL doesn't really care, though. AFAIK it's fine with aliases in WHERE clauses.

Comment: `"Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause. This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined."` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html

Comment: @Wiseguy looks like I was flat out wrong. Thanks! Have corrected the query.

Comment: Yay! I've been eager to upvote this. lol One last gripe: `HAVING` goes before `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
(CASE WHEN Field1 = Value1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+CASE WHEN Field2 = Value2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
...
+CASE WHEN FieldN = ValueN THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
)
AS Conditions
From YourTable
WHERE Conditions >= (Min_Number_Of_Fields)
```