# MySQL query with multiple conditions not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I have several tables:

**videos**

- id
- ch_id
- title
- date_published

**channels**

- id
- title

**tags**

- id
- title

**video_tags**

- v_id
- t_id

Using those tables, I am trying to select videos related to another video using tags. In my current attempt, I've tried the following:

```
SELECT v.id v_id, ch.id ch_id, ch.title ch_title,
       v.title v_title, v.date_published v_date_published
    FROM videos v
    JOIN channels ch ON ch.id = v.ch_id
    JOIN video_tags vt ON vt.v_id = v.id
    WHERE v.id NOT LIKE 'example_id'
    AND (((vt.t_id = 1) + (vt.t_id = 2) + (vt.t_id = 3) + (vt.t_id = 4)) >= 2)
    GROUP BY v.id ORDER BY v.date_published LIMIT 10;
```

However, this does not work. I do not get errors, but I get 0 results back when I know there should be more results.

I've spent hours thinking about it and looking for answers online. Maybe I'm using the wrong words in my searches, but I haven't been able to find a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First you are assigning `v` to the table `videos` --  and so on .. These "should" be included in your SELECT -- IE `SELECT v.v_id, ch.ch_id` etc etc

Comment: why did you have this? AND (((t_id = 1) + (t_id = 2) + (t_id = 3) + (t_id = 4)) >= 2)

Comment: I don't understand why you didn't get errors :)

Comment: It would help if you clarify exactly what you're trying to do. I think you're trying to select a video if it has at least two tags from a specific set of four, is that right? (Please edit the question, don't reply with a comment.)

The way you're trying to do that unfortunately isn't going to work. The reason I'm answering in a comment rather than an answer is that it's not immediately obvious to me how to do what you want in a SQL query. If the database is small you may want to consider doing it in app code instead.

Comment: @Zak that's how it is in my code, I was just trying to simplify it for the question, but I fixed it in the question now.

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar I wrote that code so that the videos I get back have at least 2 tags in common.

Comment: you will always have >=2 on that. why didn't you just use t_id>=2?

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar I'm not sure I follow what you're saying... I'm not trying to see if t_id is greater than a given value. I'm trying to see if it matches any one of a given set of values... The tag IDs could've been 10, 3, 150, and 1900. I just used 1, 2, 3, and 4 as an example.

Comment: nevermind that, i just realized what you wanted on that. you answered this "@FerdinandGaspar I wrote that code so that the videos I get back have at least 2 tags in common." when I wrote about t_id >=2 so i didn't read it before

Comment: @GlennWillen That is correct, I'm trying to see if a video has at least 2 tags from a given set. I thought it would've been pretty straight forward as I was following this tutorial on how to check for x or more conditions as true: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109375/mysql-matching-2-out-of-5-fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're doing the addition of all the `vt.t_id = X` comparisons in the `WHERE` clause. That gets executed for one row at a time, it doesn't operate on the aggregate of all rows in each group. You should do it in a `HAVING` clause, using `SUM()` to combine all the rows.

```
SELECT v.v_id, ch.ch_id, ch.ch_title, v.v_title, v.v_date_published
FROM videos v
JOIN channels ch ON ch.ch_id = v.ch_id
JOIN video_tags vt ON vt.v_id = v.v_id
WHERE v.v_id != 'example_id'
GROUP BY v.v_id 
HAVING SUM(vt.t_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)) >= 2
ORDER BY v.v_date_published LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: `vt.t_id IN (...)` is `1` if the ID is in the list, `0` otherwise. It sums these results for all the rows in the group for `v.v_id`. Then `HAVING` keeps the row in the result set if the sum is at least 2.

Answer (score 0):

One, your **selectors** are wrong in the `SELECT` statement, your `AND` statement, your `JOIN` statement, and your `GROUP BY` statement.  --  IE `v.v_id`

Two, your `LIKE` statement is likely failing without the `%` parameter

```
SELECT v.v_id, ch.ch_id, ch.ch_title, v.v_title, v.v_date_published
FROM videos v
JOIN channels ch ON ch.ch_id = v.ch_id
JOIN video_tags vt ON vt.v_id = v.v_id
WHERE v.v_id NOT LIKE '%example_id%'
AND (((vt.t_id = 1) + (vt.t_id = 2) + (vt.t_id = 3) + (vt.t_id = 4)) >= 2)
GROUP BY v.v_id ORDER BY v.v_date_published LIMIT 10;
```

**NOTE** This is assuming your `AND` Statement is correct!  I am just pointing out the syntactical errors!

Comment: I fixed the selectors as per your earlier comment. As to your second point, it's an ID that I'm first selecting from the database in another query, then using that ID in this query, I don't think the `%` modifier is necessary there. Everything in my query works as intended without the second part of the `WHERE` clause, that is the part after the `AND` and before the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @user4181107 If you're not doing a pattern match, it should be `!=` rather than `NOT LIKE`.

Comment: However, MySQL is smart enough to notice that the value doesn't have any wildcards, so it will treat `LIKE` or `NOT LIKE` as if you'd written `=` or `!=` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Use HAVING COUNT for the tag id instead

```
SELECT v.id v_id, 
       ch.id ch_id, 
       ch.title ch_title,
       v.title v_title, 
       v.date_published v_date_published
  FROM videos v
  JOIN channels ch 
    ON ch.id = v.ch_id
  JOIN video_tags vt 
    ON vt.v_id = v.id
 WHERE v.id NOT LIKE 'example_id'
 GROUP BY v.id 
HAVING COUNT(vt.t_id) >= 2
 ORDER BY v.date_published 
 LIMIT 10;
```